# Suppose I have two functions which I know are homotopic to one another. Is there software I can use to find a homotopy between them?

Tags: homotopy-theory, computational-mathematics

Ideally, this would be something working on a numerical level, rather than symbolic. For more context, I have two sound samples: One of a standard English speaker pronouncing a phoneme (a basic unit of speech), and one of a person with a speech impediment pronouncing a phoneme. Both of these samples can be modeled with continuous functions, and those functions approximated by polynomials, so the goal is to find an approximation of a homotopy between those functions.

Comment: Maybe I am not aware of some more applied usage of the term "homotopy", but in this case I'm not sure that any old homotopy is what you want. The codomain of a waveform is usually taken to be something contractible, so any two continuous functions will be homotopic, by going via a constant function. Would you like your homotopy to be somehow more minimal or more information-preserving than this? Linear interpolation is already a bit better, though probably still not very helpful if you're not in frequency space.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, you're right in that I wouldn't want just any homotopy. Something that is computationally minimal but still preserves as much information as possible; ideally, given two functions $S_1, S_2$ which represent two phonemes $P_1, P_2$ respectively, the homotopy would be some $\phi$ such that $\phi(S_1) = S_2$. I'm trying to mathematically model the relationship between standard speech and non-standard speech at the phonemic level, and this seemed like a good route.